# Printing full stack trace from invocation root when try/catching exception in Python?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch, stack-trace, traceback

**How can one log the entire stack trace when logging a caught exception, just like it would if the exception wasn't caught?**

Currently it only includes stack up until the try/catch block, but not above.

```py
def a():
    raise RuntimeError('Error!')

a()
```

Will print

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY_FILE", line 16, in <module>
    a()
  File "MY_FILE.py", line 7, in a
    raise RuntimeError('Error!')
RuntimeError: Error!
```

While catching the same error with try/catch

```py
def a():
    try:
        raise RuntimeError('Error!')
    except Exception as ex:
        traceback.print_exc() # or traceback.print_tb(ex.__traceback__) or logger.exception('', exc_info=True)
a()
```

Will print only

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MY_FILE.py", line 9, in a
    raise RuntimeError('Error!')
RuntimeError: Error!
```

Any stack trace above the try/catch scope is left out. In example above it's trivial, but what if a() was called from a large number of places within the application? The context of the error may partially be the cause of the error being created, where full stack trace would make debugging much easier. Any idea how to get full trace exception logged, apart from `traceback.print_stack()`?

Comment: Python's stack trace system is weird. It builds stack traces by adding a new entry every time an exception propagates up another stack frame, rather than by actually inspecting what the stack looks like when the exception is created or thrown. The "true" stack trace is often impossible to recover.

Comment: The closest you can get is usually stitching together information from a traceback and information about the current state of the stack, such as by calling both `traceback.print_exc()` and `traceback.print_stack()`, but while such combined information is useful, the meanings of the two sides don't quite fit together.

Comment: That's an interesting insight. Yes, I thought merging `print_exc` and `print_stack` would be a manual way to do it. Didn't think it bubbles like that though, so thanks for sharing the knowledge.